# Unable to add interceptor for service bean with Jersey

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, spring-aop, jersey-2.0

I am writing REST web service with Jersey 2.6. 
I am providing service bean (entry point to the service) in web.xml as

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey_REST</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>    
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.my.abc.webservices</param-value>
    </init-param> 
</servlet>
```

And this package (com.my.abc.webservices) contains service bean (entry point to the web service) as  :

```
 package com.my.abc.webservices;
    @Service("caseWebService")
    @Path("/CaseService")
    public class CaseWebService {
    ----
    }
```

And in spring application context I want to add one method interceptor to the above bean, in this way:

```
<bean
        class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanNameAutoProxyCreator">
        <property name="beanNames" value="caseWebService" />  
        <property name="interceptorNames">
            <list>
                  <value>traceInterceptor</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

This trace interceptor is nothing but logging interceptor which logs the parameters passed to service methods.

PROBLEM: Interceptor is not getting called.

But if I add these interceptor to some other bean by changing `<property name="beanNames" value="myHandler" />` as required, interceptors are getting called.

Suspicion:  Is it because "caseWebService" initialization has something to do with Jersey (I thought Spring will still take ownership in initializing this bean "caseWebService" because we have given @Service on it, and Jersery will only look into provider package to find the entry bean, if that is the case then why spring is not able to proxy that "caseWebService" hence not able to add interceptors ) whereas "myHandler" bean is initialized by Spring itself.

Comment: I don't know about Jersey, but if that class is something that Jersey initializes (it's using 'new') and uses, it's useless if you add `@Service`. Spring will create its own instance, Jersey its own and if in your app the one that Jersey initializes is used, then it's not proxied.

Comment: Why not using [Jersey Spring integration](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/spring.html)?